# Mac M1 rbenv and ruby -v do not match

Tags: ruby, apple-m1, rbenv

Thoughs as to why on an Apple M1

rbenv lists:

```
 rbenv versions
  system
  2.7.6
* 3.1.2 (set by /Users/xxxxxx/.rbenv/version)
```

and `ruby -v` shows:

```
ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.arm64e-darwin21
```

Comment: Because you forgot to run `rbenv init` and do what it tells you?

Comment: In particular, make sure to add what it says to your `.profile` or equivalent and relaunch your shell or `source` that first.

Comment: Thanks @matt, the init is what I missed!

Comment: Yes, I know. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter this command in your terminal:

```
eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"
```

Comment: Add this command in shell config file